# Exchange 2010: configure remote wipe notifications

Tags: exchange-2010, remote-access

When users (or administrators) initiate a remote device wipe on Exchange 2010, the user gets a confirmation message delivered to her mailbox upon a successful wipe. It seems that this message is being localized according to the reported language of the mobile device which we do not want.

Are there ways to either customize this notification message or at least make sure that all remote wipe confirmation messages delivered within the organization are sent in English only?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking for are these transport server properties:

```
InternalDsnDefaultLanguage
ExternalDsnDefaultLanguage
InternalDsnLanguageDetectionEnabled
ExternalDsnLanguageDetectionEnabled
```

These can be set via PowerShell. Check out [this article](http://christianlechner.blogspot.com/2011/02/change-exchange-ndr-message-language.html) for more information on their usage. It talks about using them to control the language used in an NDR, but I'm assuming they'll take effect on any Exchange system messages.

As for actually customizing the message text, you might be able to follow the procedure in [this TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb125230), but I'm not certain. I haven't actually seen one of the wipe confirmation messages before, so I don't know if it has a DSN identifier in it or not.